# Unable to set CSS style for div

Tags: html, css, angular

I am very new to `CSS` and was unable to figure out how to place all the contents inside my `div` at the same level. I am facing an issue while trying to set the `actual price` value (**striked off**) next to the `discounted price` in the card. It's getting placed under the tag which I don't want. Any suggestion on how to improve my `CSS` logic? Thanks.

[image: actual price appearing below tag]

Here's my code:

```css
#products {
  padding-top: 3%;
  display:fixed;
  position: inherit;
  margin: 0 auto 0 auto;  
}
#product-content {
  margin-bottom: 5%;
  padding-bottom: 2%;
}
.mat-card-title {
  cursor:pointer;
  white-space: pre-line;
}
#tag {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 1%;
  width: 6rem;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  background-color: darkorange;
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
}
#category {
  float:left;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 25%;
  margin-top: -2.6%;
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}
#wishlist {
  float:left;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 35%;
  margin-top: -3%;
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  width: 2rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#discounted-price{
  float:left;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 43%;
  margin-top: -2.6%;
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}
#discounted-price {
  float:left;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 57%;
  margin-top: -2.6%;
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}
#displayOriginalPrice {
  float:left;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 60%;
  margin-top: -2.6%;
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}
#add-to-cart{
  float:left;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: -3.1%;
  margin-left: 65%;
  padding-top: 0.5%;
  width: 8rem;
  height: 2rem;
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
  text-align:center;
  background-color: darkorange;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" id="products">
  <mat-card
    class="product-content"
    *ngFor="let product of products"
    id="product-content">
    <mat-card-header>
      <mat-card-title (click)="navigate()">{{ product.name }}</mat-card-title>
    </mat-card-header>
    <mat-card-content>
      <div>
        <div id="tag">{{ product.tags }}</div>
        <div id="category">{{ product.category }}</div>
        <div id="wishlist" (click)="addToWishList(product)">
          <i
            [ngStyle]="{ color: product.isInWishList ? 'yellow' : '' }"
            class="fa fa-star-o fa-2x"
            aria-hidden="true"
          ></i>
        </div>
        <div id="discounted-price">Rs. {{ getDiscountedPrice(product) }}/-</div>
        <div
          id="actual-price"
          *ngIf="product.discountedPerc === 0; else displayOriginalPrice">-</div>
        <ng-template id="displayOriginalPrice" #displayOriginalPrice>{{
          product.actualPrice
        }}</ng-template>
        <div id="add-to-cart">ADD TO CART</div>
      </div>
    </mat-card-content>
  </mat-card>
</div>
```

Comment: `flexbox` would be a better solution for this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a case where CSS `FLEX` will work *beautifully*. `FLEX` is used in CSS layouts to align items in one row, just like this!

```css
#products {
  padding-top: 3%;
  display: fixed;
  position: inherit;
  margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
}

#product-content {
  margin-bottom: 5%;
  padding-bottom: 2%;
}

.mat-card-title {
  cursor: pointer;
  white-space: pre-line;
}

#tag {
  position: relative;
  width: 6rem;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  background-color: darkorange;
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
}

#category {
  position: relative;
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

#wishlist {
  position: relative;
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  width: 2rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#discounted-price {
  position: relative;
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

#displayOriginalPrice {
  position: relative;
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  /* Strike 'em off */
  text-decoration: line-through;
}

#add-to-cart {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 0.5%;
  width: 8rem;
  height: 2rem;
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: darkorange;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/* Align Items With  */

.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container" id="products">
  <mat-card class="product-content" *ngFor="let product of products" id="product-content">
    <mat-card-header>
      <mat-card-title (click)="navigate()">NAME</mat-card-title>
    </mat-card-header>
    <mat-card-content>
      <div class="flex-container">
        <div id="tag">AWESOME</div>
        <div id="category">HTML</div>
        <div id="wishlist" (click)="addToWishList(product)">
          <i [ngStyle]="{ color: product.isInWishList ? 'yellow' : '' }" class="fa fa-star-o fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </div>
        <div id="discounted-price">WEB</div>
        <div id="actual-price" *ngIf="product.discountedPerc === 0; else displayOriginalPrice">-</div>
        <ng-template id="displayOriginalPrice" #displayOriginalPrice>SITE</ng-template>
        <div id="add-to-cart">ADD TO CART</div>
      </div>
    </mat-card-content>
  </mat-card>
</div>
```

I added CSS to *strike-off* the price values by adding `text-decoration: line-through`.

Just note I removed `float` and `margin` values so that FLEX works properly.

Have a look at `FLEX` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex)!

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="container" id="products">
      <mat-card
        class="product-content"
        *ngFor="let product of products"
        id="product-content">
        <mat-card-header>
          <mat-card-title (click)="navigate()">{{ product.name }}</mat-card-title>
        </mat-card-header>
        <mat-card-content>
          <div>
            <div id="tag">{{ product.tags }}</div>
            <div id="category">{{ product.category }}</div>
            <div id="wishlist" (click)="addToWishList(product)">
              <i
                [ngStyle]="{ color: product.isInWishList ? 'yellow' : '' }"
                class="fa fa-star-o fa-2x"
                aria-hidden="true"
              ></i>
            </div>
            <div id="discounted-price">Rs. {{ getDiscountedPrice(product) }}/-</div>
            <div
              id="actual-price"
              *ngIf="product.discountedPerc === 0; else displayOriginalPrice">-</div>
            <ng-template  #displayOriginalPrice id="displayOriginalPrice"><div> {{
              product.actualPrice
            }}</div></ng-template>
            <div id="add-to-cart">ADD TO CART</div>
          </div>
        </mat-card-content>
      </mat-card>
    </div>
```

Add the div in ng template